Change bibtex export style citation key
I would like to export from my EndNote21 Library to bibtex, with the citation key being something like "". When I export, the resulting entry has the record number as a citation key:
@article{RN50,
   author = {Doe, J.},
   title = {foo},
   year = {2024},
   ...
}

What I want is something like:
@article{Doe_2024,
   author = {Doe, J.},
   title = {foo},
   year = {2024},
   ...
}

How do I change the export style settings so this is generated by default? I tried changing  `RN`Record Number into Author_Date in the style manager under Bibliogrpahy -> Templates, but it generates an ultra long citation key from ALL authors.
Thank you!
